# Basic molecular biology of nucleic acids book for a mathematician studying DNA and RNA formally?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, bioinformatics, rna, literature

I am a mathematician studying DNA and RNA language from the perspective of [Formal Language Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar).
Note that I am aware of these posts:

> [best book for a comprehensive introduction to biology for a computer science graduate interested in undertaking research in bioinformatics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35382/best-book-for-a-comprehensive-introduction-to-biology-for-a-computer-science-gra)
>
> [Introductory biology text for an outsider](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10376/introductory-biology-text-for-an-outsider)
>
> [Material recommendation: molecular biology for mathematicians and computer scientists](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/46191/material-recommendation-molecular-biology-for-mathematicians-and-computer-scien)

I consider my situation more specific, I am specifically dealing with DNA and RNA, so what I need is a basic text that deals with this two structures, rigorous but still accessible.

As an example I quote a paper I am reading:

> (...) Inverted repeats are prevalent features of nucleic acids (...)

I would like trustable references for the fact that these *features* indeed exist, which is fundamental for my work, and maybe a shallow explanation for what they biologically imply, but I do not want to delve into what these *features* mean (It would be great to understand them from a biological perspective but that is not my priority)